# Android restrict my apk file to get backup

Tags: android

I want to restrict my app get backup from the other Backup & restore Apps, is there any solution available programmatically,if u found anything related means help me thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to say you don't want someone to access the apk of the installed app from device, then it is not possible. Android stores the apk of installed app at a certain path and it can be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make 100% possible to restrict user to take back up. But I can say few possible ways to restrict.

1. File Observer. To monitor where it gets stored and delete it.
2. Another way is find some way of back up file storage location of application and prevent user to store it.

   ```
      For eg: If application  use /am/ <location> to take backup means,
      File f = new File("/am/");
      if(f.exists("<nameof your application>.apk"))
      {
      f.delete();
       }
   ```

   and download few application and see where the application getting stored as backup and do the above stuffs to prevent some standard apk back up which user uses often.

   But still I am saying you can't give 100% bullet proof for your application.

Comment: thanks for your reply, simply i want to restrict my application apk file get backup by  the Appbackup&restore application which is present in the market, so for that restriction is there any way to do programmatically? help me thanks in advance

Comment: @Rajajisubramanian yes that's what I am saying, for eg: es file explorer and some App back up application will make the app to use back up file location as am/folder in sd card. make to restrict that to prevent back up of that location. So by doing that, your application will be prevented for back up.